# DocuSign's Java SDK: Add 'Recipient Company Name' to Signer/Recipient

Tags: java, docusignapi

DocuSigns' report section includes tables containing the column name *Recipient Company Name*

[image]

I had a look through all DocuSign models inside the SDK, but I couldn't find any way to fill this column. Is there a way to do so using the SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can only be filled if the recipient is either a :

1. Saved contact in your DocuSign account.
2. Has their own DocuSign account.

If your recipient is just a random email/name you added to a one-time envelope - there's no way to enter the company information.

You can update contacts in your account and add the company name, see this [article I wrote](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-adding-contact-to-your-docusign-address-book) about how to do that in 6 languages including Java:
(note the "Organization" field which is the compan)

```
// You will need to obtain an access token using your chosen authentication flow 
Configuration config = new Configuration(new ApiClient(basePath));
config.addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
UsersApi usersApi = new UsersApi(config);
UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
Contact contact = new Contact();
contact.setName("Inbar Gazit");
contact.setEmails(new java.util.ArrayList<String>());
contact.getEmails().add("inbar.gazit@docusign.com");
contact.setOrganization("DocuSign");
ContactPhoneNumber contactPhoneNumber = new ContactPhoneNumber();
contactPhoneNumber.setPhoneNumber("212-555-1234");
contactPhoneNumber.setPhoneType("mobile");
contact.setContactPhoneNumbers(new java.util.ArrayList<ContactPhoneNumber>());
contact.getContactPhoneNumbers().add(contactPhoneNumber);
ContactModRequest contactModificationRequest = new ContactModRequest();
contactModificationRequest.setContactList(new java.util.ArrayList<Contact>());
contactModificationRequest.getContactList().add(contact);
usersApi.postContacts(accountId, contactModificationRequest);
```